# Discard "access denied" stderr natively in find

Tags: permissions, find, options, stderr

Is there an option in `find` that allows me to suppress the error messages that I get from it trying to access directories for which I don't have access?

I know I can just discard stderr, but it seems like such an obvious need that I'm not convinced that an option that does this does not exist, despite me not finding one in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *avoid* getting permission errors from `find`, you would have to avoid provoking these errors.  You do that by avoiding entering directories that are not accessible.

Find and display the pathnames of directories that are not readable by the current user, but don't descend into them, GNU `find` style:

```
find / -type d ! -readable -prune
```

The `-prune` action removes the pathname currently under investigation from the search path of `find`.

With standard `find`, you would have to combine `-perm` and `-user` and `-group` in a complicated way to test the permissions on each directory depending on the ownerships of the directory.  I think I've tried to do that a couple of times, but it's difficult.

To only care about the "others" permission bits:

```
find / -type d ! -user "$(id -u)" ! -group "$(id -g)" ! -perm -005 -prune
```

This would find any directory not owned by the current user, not belonging to the current user's group, and whose permission bits does not allow "others" to read (list) or execute (enter) it, and then prune these from the search path.

The full thing, testing all the permission bits, may possibly look something like

```
find / -type d \( \(   -user "$(id -u)"                     ! -perm -500 \) -o \
                  \( ! -user "$(id -u)"   -group "$(id -g)" ! -perm -050 \) -o \
                  \( ! -user "$(id -u)" ! -group "$(id -g)" ! -perm -005 \) \) -prune
```

The difference between this and the `-readable` of GNU `find` is that `-readable` also considers ACLs etc.

---

To *discard* permission errors from `find`, redirect its standard error stream to `/dev/null`.

Comment: That should probably be something like `find . \( ! -type d -o -readable -o -prune \) ...`

Comment: Even with that, you'll still get some error messages if there are directories that are readable but not searchable.

Comment: You'd need to consider *all* the groups the user (process) is member of. See [Find files that a user can not read?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/88591)

Answer (score 1):

You are unlikely to find many commands (if any) that have an option to suppress error messages. This is because it's trivial to discard *stderr* with a construct such as `2>/dev/null`.

In particular, `find` does not have such an option natively.